# how can a unit vector n with 3 dimensions be translated to $|+n\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems

This question comes a from problem in a quantum physics book. In Townsend's modern quantum book (A modern approach to quantum mechanics) in chapter 1 problem 1.3 there is a unit given that is $\boldsymbol n = \sin(\Delta)\cos(\phi)\,\boldsymbol i  + \sin(\Delta)\sin(\phi)\, \boldsymbol j + \cos(\Delta)\, \boldsymbol k$
then it specifies that by looking at figure 1.11 you are given 
$|+n\rangle = \cos(\Delta/2)|+z\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin(Δ/2)|-z\rangle.$

This brings me to my question, how is that so? how can you get $|+n\rangle$ from $n$? is there a way to do it or is it just by definition? excuse my ignorance, i'm just not seeing the connection. thanks in advance for anyone that can help me

Answer (score 2):

The way to prove this is to use the fact that angular momentum (including spin) is the generator of rotations. So, a rotation operator is given by
$$\hat{R}(\theta,\mathbf{a}) = \exp\left(i \theta \frac{\hat{\mathbf{L}}\cdot\mathbf{a}}{\hbar}\right),$$
where $\mathbf{a}$ is the unit vector axis of rotation and $\theta$ is the angle.

For spin-$^1/_2$, we have the components of $\hat{\mathbf{L}}$ in the $\hat{S}_z$-basis are
\begin{align}
  \hat{L}_x =\hat{S}_x &= \frac{\hbar}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
      0 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 \end{array}\right], \\
  \hat{L}_y =\hat{S}_x &= \frac{\hbar}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
      0 & -i \\
      i & 0 \end{array}\right],\ \text{and} \\
  \hat{L}_z =\hat{S}_x &= \frac{\hbar}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & -1 \end{array}\right],
\end{align}
which is just $\hbar/2$ times the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

The rest is figuring out what combination of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\theta$ rotates the positive $z$-direction unit vector $\mathbf{k}$ into $\mathbf{n}$, constructing the matrix exponential, and applying it to $|z+\rangle$ and $|z-\rangle$ to get your new basis. You can also do it in two steps/rotations, requiring you to compute two matrix exponentials but simplifying the algebra of each considerably.

That is left as an exercise to the reader, since I know for a fact that this is a homework problem from Townsend.

The relationship to $3$-d vectors comes from using a different set of $\hat{\mathbf{L}}$ opertors. See, $3$-d vectors are spin-$1$, so you need $3\times3$ matrices to rotate them. They are described in a funny basis, though. For spin-$^1/_2$ standard practice is to work in an eigenbasis of exactly one component of the spin, $S_z$. If the spin-1 $\hat{L}_z$ eigenbasis is given by $|z_+\rangle$, $|z_0\rangle$, and $|z_-\rangle$, then the standard basis we use for ordinary vectors is: $|x_0\rangle$, $|y_0\rangle$, and $|z_0\rangle$. In that basis we have:
\begin{align}
  \hat{L}_x &= \frac{\hbar}{i} \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & -1 \\
      0 & 1 & 0\end{array}\right], \\
  \hat{L}_y &= \frac{\hbar}{i} \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 & 0 & 1 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      -1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right],\ \text{and} \\
  \hat{L}_z &= \frac{\hbar}{i} \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
      0 & -1 & 0 \\
      1 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right],
\end{align}
as ca be seen by taking the derivative of the [three basic rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) with respect to $\theta$ in $3$-d, doing the same for $\hat{R}(\theta,\mathbf{a})$ above, setting them equal to each other, and then setting $\theta=0$. For practice, I would recommend reconstructing at least one of those three matrices using the technique above. Hint: start by calculating $\hat{\mathbf{L}}_i^1$, $\hat{\mathbf{L}}_i^2$, etc, until you find the pattern, then use that pattern to group like terms in $\exp(x)=1+x+x^2/2 +\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the book, but I guess that the context is the Bloch sphere, which is a model of a state space of a 1-qubit system.

A given point **n** on the sphere is described by a pair of coordinates $(\Delta, \Phi)$, and the state it encodes is denoted $|\mathbf{n}\rangle$. The only thing that misses is what state this corresponds to in the ordinary (vector space) representation of the state space: if $|+z\rangle, |-z\rangle$ form an orthonormal basis of your state space, then this state, corresponding to the point **n** on the sphere, corresponds to the linear combination of the basis states that you wrote down.

In the end this is just a convention, but a nice one when $|+z\rangle$ and $|-z\rangle$ correspond to spin up and spin down in the $z$-direction. In that case any pair of antipodal points form the orthonormal basis of eigenstates of spin along the line that connects them.